# Получение адреса процесса

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Как получить адрес запуска процесса (как у dll, если мы грузим ее при помощи loadlibrary), если его запуск происходит в контексте текущего процесса?
Запускаю процесс при помощи:

```
CreateProcess(PATH, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &proc_info)
```

Comment: У библиотеки можно получить адреса, так как подгружается в адресное пространство этого процесса. При создании нового процесса у него будет свое адресное пространство, недоступное этому.

Comment: @user7860670, а как тогда получить адрес запуска этого процесса?